# How to structure my data in Firebase using NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

How I want my data to be structured is as follows:

> Student -> Reg_num -> someindex (that will start from 1 - like an
>   unique key) -> course details.

[image]

However, the code I wrote gives me an incorrect structure. Can someone help me sort it out.

```
var db = admin.database();
var ref = db.ref("Students");
var newMessageRef = ref.push();

exports.uploadFile = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
      cors(req, res, () => {
        var uniqueID = 97888888888888;
        if (req.method !== 'POST') {
            return res.status(500).json({
                message: 'Not allowed'
            })
        } else {
             return newMessageRef.set({
              [uniqueID]: {
                course: req.body.course,
                credits: req.body.credit,
                lecturer : 'Prof. Lee'
              }
            }).then(() => {

               res.status(200).json({
                   message: "okkkkasss"
                });
 ...
```

Note: The `-LC-lS2HPMbZW9AdT19K` is a code that was automatically added from the code. This is because I used `ref.push()`

[image]

Comment: What’s wrong exactly? Unless the fact that the index is not exactly 0,1,2 etc I don’t see a difference beteeen the desired structure and what you get.

Comment: I need to flip the positions of `97888888888888` (which is the student ID) with the uniqueCourseKey (`-LC-lS2HPMbZW9AdT19K`) - which I want it to be 0,1,2 etc. I want to list all courses undertaken by student under their student ID. So, there'll be a Node that will be student ID,and when I expand it I will be able to see all the courses undertaken by the student.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use `ref.push()` or `ref.set()`, but `ref.update()` as follows:

```
const db = admin.database();
const ref = db.ref("Students");
//var newMessageRef = ref.push();  <- Don't do that

exports.uploadFile = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
      cors(req, res, () => {

        const uniqueID = 97888888888888;  <- Student ID
        const uniqueCourseKey = 0;  <- uniqueCourseKey

        if (req.method !== 'POST') {
            return res.status(500).json({
                message: 'Not allowed'
            })
        } else {
             return ref.child(uniqueID).update({
                  [uniqueCourseKey]: {
                        course: req.body.course,
                        credits: req.body.credit,
                        lecturer : 'Prof. Lee'
                      }         
               }).then(() => {
                   res.status(200).json({
                   message: "okkkkasss"
                });
....
```

Then you can call again the Cloud Function with e.g. `const uniqueCourseKey = 1`;  and the new node will be correctly added under the `StudentID` node.

The doc for the update method is here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#update

Comment: Renaud Tarnec, you recommend not use push in this case or 'never' use push? You can explain better this?
thanks

Comment: @lesimoes push will create a new data using a unique key that is automatically generated, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#push. The key will be something like -IKo28nwJLH0Nc5XeFmj. This will be perfectly ok in most cases, but the OP wanted to use his own keys. Since he wanted to update a node, I suggested to use update(). He could have used set() but in this case he would overwrite the existing data at the node. Hope this helps.

Comment: @lesimoes So in other words, I don't recommend "to never use push()". Just choose the method based on your needs: set, push or update